# SSO Azure AD Authentication via POST using Oauth2 - PHP

Tags: php, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I have written a code to login using Azure AD it is working fine but when I redirect it to the next page the session variable with the values gets empty I have pasted the code for reference.

```
$appid = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"; //(MASKING DATA FOR OBVIOUS REASONS)

$tennantid = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"; //(MASKING DATA FOR OBVIOUS REASONS)

$secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"; //(MASKING DATA FOR OBVIOUS REASONS)

$login_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" . $tennantid . "/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";

session_start();
$_SESSION['state'] = session_id();
echo "MS OAuth2.0 Demo ";
if (isset($_SESSION['msatg'])) {
    echo "Authenticated " . $_SESSION["uname"] . "  ";
    echo 'Log Out';
} else {
    echo 'You can Log In with Microsoft';
}

if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'login') {
    $params = array('client_id' => $appid, 'redirect_uri' => 'https://abc.xyz.com/sso/', 'response_type' => 'token', 'response_mode' => 'form_post', 'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read', 'state' => $_SESSION['state']);
    header('Location: ' . $login_url . '?' . http_build_query($params));
}
if (array_key_exists('access_token', $_POST)) {
    $_SESSION['t'] = $_POST['access_token'];
    $t = $_SESSION['t'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $t,
        'Content-type: application/json'
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $rez = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), 1);


    if (array_key_exists('error', $rez)) {
        var_dump($rez);
        die();
    } else {
        $_SESSION['msatg'] = 1;  //auth and verified
        $_SESSION['uname'] = $rez["displayName"];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $rez["id"];
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    header('Location: https://abc.xyz.com/sso/welcome.php');
}

if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'logout') {
    unset($_SESSION['msatg']);
    header('Location: https://abc.xyz.com/sso/');
}
```

When it get redirected to the welcome.php page it give me an empty array of session when I var_dump $_SESSION;

I want my data of the session to get reflected on the welcome.php page

Can someone please explain what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does `welcome.php` use `session_start()`?

Comment: Do your `header` calls work when you have `echo "MS OAuth2.0 Demo ";` as output before them?

Comment: Yes it does have session_start(). it also echoes MS OAuth2.0 Demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I used `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()` by Output buffering can sometimes interfere with session data.

**Code :**

```php
<?php
ob_start(); 

session_start();

$appid = "<client_id>"; 
$tennantid = "<tenant_id>"; 
$secret = "<client_secret>"; 
$login_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" . $tennantid . "/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";

$_SESSION['state'] = session_id();

if (isset($_SESSION['msatg'])) {
    echo "Authenticated " . $_SESSION["uname"] . "  ";
    echo '<a href="?action=logout">Log Out</a>';
} else {
    echo "MS OAuth2.0 Demo ";
    echo '<a href="?action=login">Log In with Microsoft</a>';
}

if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'login') {
    $params = array(
        'client_id' => $appid,
        'redirect_uri' => 'https://abc.xyz.com/sso/',
        'response_type' => 'token',
        'response_mode' => 'form_post',
        'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read',
        'state' => $_SESSION['state']
    );
    header('Location: ' . $login_url . '?' . http_build_query($params));
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['access_token'])) {
    $_SESSION['t'] = $_POST['access_token'];
    $t = $_SESSION['t'];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $t,
        'Content-type: application/json'
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $rez = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

    if (isset($rez['error'])) {
        var_dump($rez);
        die();
    } else {
        $_SESSION['msatg'] = 1; 
        $_SESSION['uname'] = $rez["displayName"];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $rez["id"];
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    header('Location: https://abc.xyz.com/sso/welcome.php');
    exit();
}

if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'logout') {
    unset($_SESSION['msatg']);
    header('Location: https://abc.xyz.com/sso/');
    exit();
}

ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

I added the below URL to the App Redirect URL as below,

[image]

**Output :**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

I got the below output with above output URL. Then, I click on **Log In with Microsoft as below**,

[image]

I was logged in with my account as below,

[image]

Below is the data that I can retrieve, and this is how the sessions work in the PHP configuration.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I was redirecting it to the same page. I made the following changes in
1) 'redirect_uri' => 'https://abc.xyz.com/sso/' -> 'redirect_uri' => 'https://abc.xyz.com/sso/welcome.php'
2) Also (if (isset($_POST['access_token'])) { .....) code should be placed in the welcome.php page.

Thanks for the help